# Get DataBase name from Hibernate.cfg.xml through java program

Tags: java, hibernate

I just want to know how we can get the database name from the `hibernate.cfg.xml` using a java program

Can anyone please help me to get the database name.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: You want to know how to "parse" that XML file and extract the database name? Or you want to know how to get the configured database name _at runtime_ using Hibernate classes?

Answer (score 1):

Use `hibernate.properties` instead of `hibernate.cfg.xml`

And in hibernate.properties,,,u can put these properties for database :-

`hibernate.database.application=database_name`

And u can easily find database name by following code :-

```
private static Properties props;
props = new Properties();     
props.load(PropertiesManager.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("hibernate.properties"));
String databaseNmae = prop.getProperty("hibernate.database.application");
```